# Two Bedrock severs on the same local network, access via Friends on PS4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4, networking

I’ve got two Minecraft servers running in a Docker. Each server runs on a different port: Bedrock_Server_1 on default port 19132 and the Bedrock_Server_2 on non-standard port 19140.

I can access them from most devices, but not from my PS4. PS4 doesn’t support servers yet. But it does support “Friends” and I can connect to one of my servers, the one that uses the default port 19132.

I wonder if it would be possible to make the Server_2 appear as a separate device (with e. g. different IP) with the default port 19132?

I was trying to redirect the port with the Proxy running on the Raspi but got stuck...

Sorry if it is a noob question...

I have attached schematics:
[image]

Comment: I think it could be set-up with a VLAN, so each container has a separate local IP and runs on a default port, but I wasn’t able to find any good examples on how to do it on a MacOS.

Comment: Multipass solution looks more promising than Docker as it offers unique local IPs for  containers out-of-the-box.

Comment: I must state that what you are doing is not allowed by Sony, Xbox Team, nor Nintendo. Mojang Studios also is not to be held responsible if your device(s) and / or network gets compromised, or even if your devices / accounts get banned from online services due to bypassing the official methods. This can easily cause malware to be installed (including updates that cause the gaming device to be "bricked"), and / or your account login information leaked to third parties by a [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), thus I do not recommend continuing to ci

Answer (score 1):

Bedrock servers don't show up as LAN games unless they're on the default port. There is a command which can be executed on servers to transfer a player to another server (/transferserver). This works with PS4 to send it to any server. So run a dummy server whose sole purpose is to provide a hub world. Wire buttons to command blocks in this hub world which will run the transferserver command and connect the player to the other servers.

Comment: I tried `transferserver` but it doesn’t seem to work on the official Bedrock server right now. (It is also possible that I type it incorrectly)